# change service fabric endpoint port in Azure Api Management from portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How do I change the endpoint port for Service fabric from 19000 to 19080 in API Managment? When following the quick setup example in API Managment made the mistake 
`http://mktestsf2.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000`
instead of
`http://mktestsf2.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080`

How do I change this in the portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it through https://resources.azure.com. In there, navigate to your subscription > your resource group > Providers > Microsoft.APIManagement > your API Management Service > backends > servicefabric. Make sure you are in read/write mode. Click edit, change the managementEndpoints and resourceID if necessary, and then click PUT.

You can also change it through Azure RM Powershell. To get the backend details:

```
$apimContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "RGName" -ServiceName "APIM_Name"
Get-AzureRmApiManagementBackend -Context $apimContext
```

To change the resourceID and managementEndpoint:

```
$sf=(Get-AzureRmApiManagementBackend -Context $apimContext).ServiceFabricCluster
$sf.ManagementEndpoints="https://mysfcluster123.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080"
Set-AzureRmApiManagementBackend -Context $apimContext -resourceId "https://mysfcluster123.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080" -BackendId servicefabric -ServiceFabricCluster $sf
```